# Django: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'. What format date/time do I need?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting `'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'` error from the `timesince` filter in django. It was working fine previously with strings in this format: `"2013-06-20"`. However I've now updated the string to include an time element: `"2013-06-20T11:20:05.499274"` causing this error.

What format do I need to give it to handle the time element? Or do I need to do some extra processing in the view?

Comment: I'm surprised `timesince` would even work with strings - the docs imply it needs `date` objects.

Comment: in that case i'm surprised aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`timesince` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) only accepts dates, not date and time combinations. It displays the time difference from the current time (or optionally, a passed in date to compare with).

In your view, parse that string to its date component only. If it you already have it as a datetime object, simply call `.date()` on it to get the date part.

If you have it as a string:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
date_only = datetime.strptime("2013-06-20T11:20:05.499274", fmt).date()
```

Comment: ah crazy I assumed it accepted date time combinations not just dates. I'll have to look for another solution to get the amount of time from a date/time combination.